# How do I use terraform to connect a replica Postgres RDS and its Source in a different VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to set up a dev environment: 1x private subnet, 1x public subnet in the dev VPC; Postgres RDS instance in the private subnet; each subnet's resources are in its own security group.  The source RDS instance is in the prod VPC.  I have created a peering connection and the CIDRs of each VPC do not over lap.

I am getting

> Error: Error creating DB Instance: InvalidParameterCombination: The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs. The DB instance is in prod-vpc and the EC2 security group is in dev-vpc

Here are my terraform defintions.  I have also added the other peer's relevant CIDRs to the route tables of each peer VPC.  The source RDS and prod VPC were both created in a separate process and already exist outside of this terraform process.

```
module "vpc" {
  source               = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version              = "2.77.0"
  name                 = "dev-vpc"
  cidr                 = "192.168.0.0/16"
  azs                  = ["us-west-2a"]
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true
}

module "keypair" {
  source      = "git::https://github.com/rhythmictech/terraform-aws-secretsmanager-keypair"
  name_prefix = "ec2-ssh"
  description = "SSH keypair for instances"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "dev-sg-pub" {
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
  ingress {
    from_port   = 5432 # testing
    to_port     = 5432 # testing
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["192.168.1.0/28","192.168.2.0/24"]
    self        = true
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 5432 # testing
    to_port     = 5432 # testing
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "dev-sg-priv" {
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
  ingress {
    from_port       = 5432 # testing
    to_port         = 5432 # testing
    protocol        = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks     = ["192.168.1.0/28", "192.168.2.0/24"]
    security_groups = ["sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"] # the pub subnet's sg
    self            = true
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 5432 # testing
    to_port     = 5432 # testing
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["192.168.1.0/28", "192.168.2.0/24"]
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "dev-subnet-pub" {
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id
  cidr_block  = "192.168.1.0/28"
  tags = {
    Name        = "dev-subnet-pub"
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "dev-subnet-priv" {
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id
  cidr_block  = "192.168.2.0/24"
  tags = {
    Name        = "dev-subnet-priv"
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "dev-peer-conn" {   
  peer_vpc_id   = "vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxa"
  vpc_id        = module.vpc.vpc_id
  auto_accept   = true
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "dev-replica" {
   name                   = "dev-replica"
   identifier             = "dev-replica"
   replicate_source_db    = "arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:9999999999:db:tf-xxxxxxxx"
   instance_class         = "db.t3.small"
   apply_immediately      = false
   publicly_accessible    = false
   skip_final_snapshot    = true
   vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.dev-sg-priv.id, "sg-xxxxxxxxxxx"]
   depends_on = [aws_vpc_peering_connection.dev-peer-conn]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't do this**. SGs have VAC-scope, and your RDS must use SG from the VPC it is located it.

Since you peered your VPCs, you can only reference SG across VPCs in your `aws_security_group.dev-sg-priv`.

Comment: The security group can cross the VPC boundaries?

Comment: @d8aninja Yes, you can reference it in `aws_security_group.dev-sg-priv`, but can't be used directly for your RDS.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. " A security group can be used only in the VPC for which it is created "....https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

Comment: It seems like the point of the replicas is to be able to share an updated database across different environments for developer use cases and such. Is there a suggested way to do this if not in the manner I am attempting here?

Comment: @d8aninja For development purposes it would be best to have fully separate DB, a clone of mini version of the production. Replicas are read-only, so using replica for dev purposes is only useful for testing read operations.

Comment: I was hoping to use a single RDS replica shared amongst multiple development environments each with their own read write RDS that uses the replica tables as staging tables. That way the developer RDS instances could have a copy of the updated records from prod via the replica as well as right capabilities for their own records locally

Comment: @d8aninja Your replicas have to use security groups from VPCs they are located in. There is no way around this.